# What is the difference between 'Cache Oblivious' and 'Cache agnostic'?

Tags: caching, cache-oblivious

In my studies, I came across these two words and I didn't quite understand what Cache agnostic meant. There is also little information about Cache agnostic online.

Please explain what Cache agnostic means and how it differs from Cache Oblivious!

Comment: "Cache agnostic" seems to be used mainly by non-native writers, and even then it is unusual. Isn't it just mistaken terminology, used in place of "cache oblivious"?